# Applying multiple condition on a column

Tags: sql, count

My table look like below.

```
ID  Task
1   Search
2   Basic
3   Natural search
4   Query1
5   query2
6   Query3
7   Sample1
8   sample2
9   test1
10  test2
11  test3
```

Now I need to count the values in the task column where task=(search,Basic,Natural serach) and task=(query1,Query2,Query3) and task=(sample1,sample) and task=(test1,test2,test3). I want to store every count separately like

```
count(search),count(Query),count(sample),count(test)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it with the following for your Results in one row:

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Table
WHERE task = 'search' or task = 'Basic' or task = 'natural search') AS CountSearch,
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Table
WHERE task = 'Query1' or task = 'Query2' or task = 'Query3') AS CountQuery,
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Table
WHERE task = 'sample1' or task = 'sample2') AS CountSample,
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Table
WHERE task = 'test1' or task = 'test2' or task = 'test3') AS CountTest
```

And the following for your results in several rows:

```
SELECT 'CountSearch', COUNT(*)
FROM Table
WHERE task = 'search' or task = 'Basic' or task = 'natural search'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CountQuery', COUNT(*)
FROM Table
WHERE task = 'Query1' or task = 'Query2' or task = 'Query3'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CountSample', COUNT(*)
FROM Table
WHERE task = 'sample1' or task = 'sample2'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CountTest', COUNT(*)
FROM Table
WHERE task = 'test1' or task = 'test2' or task = 'test3'
```

I renamed your columns, because you can't use brackets as columnname in a sql-statement.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want the result as rows:

```
SELECT 'Search' AS Task, COUNT(ID) AS Counts
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE task IN('search', 'Basic', 'Natural search')
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Query', COUNT(ID)
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE task IN('Query1', 'Query2', 'Query3')
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sample', COUNT(ID)
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE task IN('sample1', 'sample2')
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Test', COUNT(ID)
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE task IN('test1', 'test2', 'test3');
```

Output:

```
|   TASK | COUNTS |
|--------|--------|
| Search |      3 |
|  Query |      3 |
| Sample |      2 |
|   Test |      3 |
```

In case you want the result as columns:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN Task = 'Search' THEN  1 
            WHEN Task = 'Basic' THEN  1 
            WHEN Task = 'Natural search' THEN  1 
            ELSE 0 END) AS SEARCH 
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN Task = 'Query1' THEN  1 
            WHEN Task = 'Query2' THEN  1 
            WHEN Task = 'Query3' THEN  1 
            ELSE 0 END) AS Query 
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN Task = 'Sample1' THEN  1 
            WHEN Task = 'sample2' THEN  1 
            ELSE 0 END) AS Sample
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN Task = 'test1' THEN  1 
            WHEN Task = 'test2' THEN  1 
            WHEN Task = 'test3' THEN  1 
            ELSE 0 END) AS Test
FROM MyTable;
```

Output:

```
| SEARCH | QUERY | SAMPLE | TEST |
|--------|-------|--------|------|
|      3 |     3 |      2 |    3 |
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a70a61/11)

Comment: @Amuthan - Glad to help you! Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can accept the answer which help you. Have a look at the [about] section.